# returning from backgroundworker to calling thread from WPF dialog hosted in a Winforms app

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker, synchronizationcontext

We have a Winforms application which launches a WPF Dialog which I will refer to as the Wizard.  The purpose of the Wizard is to open a number of text files and save their contents to a database.  The time required to save these files to the DB varies from 15 to 60+ seconds.  In order to give the Wizard UI responsiveness, the process of saving the text files to the database is done on a BackgroundWorker thread.  Unfortunately, because of some legacy code in the Winforms host application, the Wizard is totally unresponsive for 80 - 90% of the time.  For that reason, the Wizard is launched on its own worker thread.

```
      

    //Put the Wizard on a separate thread to maintain UI  
    //responsiveness during the export process 
    Thread t = new Thread(LaunchBatchExportWizardView);
    t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    t.Name = "WizardThread";
    t.Start();
```

So in summary we have three principal threads, the Main thread which supports the Winforms host, the Wizard thread and the BackgroundWorker thread.  A user may pause this export process by clicking on a button on the Wizard which sends a CancelAsync message to the BackgroundWorker thread.  Inside the BackgroundWorker_DoWork event handler we check for this cancel message and, if found, discontinue processing and return.  This triggers the BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted event handler where I can check the identity of the thread to which control has been returned by using Thread.CurrentThread.Name.

The first time that the user pauses the BackgroundWorker process, control is returned to the Wizard thread.  If the user wants to resume the export process, we call RunWorkerAsync which in turn starts the  BackgroundWorker_DoWork event handler.  From observation I can see that this handler does not use the same thread which it previously used but instead uses a new one from the Thread Pool.  For debugging purposes, I give this thread a name.

```
          

    if(Thread.CurrentThread.Name == null)
    {
       Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "MyBackgroundWorkerThread" 
           + "_" + _threadCounter.ToString();
        _threadCounter++;
    }
```

The first BackgroundWorker thread is named MyBackgroundWorkerThread_1, the second one MyBackgroundWorkerThread_2, etc.

Later when the user decides to pause the process again, control is not returned to the Wizard thread in the BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted event handler (as it was the first time) but instead to some new thread.  However, this is not fatal and the user can still resume and the export process will pick up where it left off.

The problem arises, however,  when we try to launch a custom warning dialog in the event that connectivity to the database is lost.  Obviously the Wizard cannot perform its primary mission if it can't communicate with the database.  If we launch this dialog after one or more Pause / Resume cycles, an exception is thrown with the message "The calling thread must be STA, because many UI elements require this".   Because of this requirement, the Wizard thread is explicitly set to STA (see relevant code above) so if the database connectivity loss occurs before any Pause / Resume cycle, everything works just fine.   This new thread, apparently is not STA and accordingly an exception is thrown.

One option which I tried was to test to see if at the point in time that we want to launch our DatabaseConnectivityLoss dialog we are on the Wizard thread. Since the Wizard thread is an explicitly named thread (see code above), I just test to see if the name property of the current thread is null:

```
     if (Thread.CurrentThread.Name == null)
     {
         if (Application.Current == null)
         {
              new Application();
          }
          Thread t = new Thread(LaunchDatabaseConnectivityLossDialog);
          t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
          t.Name = "NewStaThread";
          t.Start();
      }
```

This works fine to launch the dialog without the previously mentioned exception but when we attempt to resume the export process after connectivity has been restored, the application hangs.

A second thing which I tried was to set a SynchronizationContext variable to hold a reference to the Wizard thread.  It was my understanding that I could use this reference to launch my DatabaseConnectivityLoss dialog on the Wizard thread regardless of what thread was current at any time.  To do this I set this variable in the constructor for the Wizard:

```
    _synchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
     if (_synchronizationContext == null)
     {//always true in my case because the wizard is a child of a Winforms app
          _synchronizationContext = new SynchronizationContext();
     }
```

However, when I later tried to use this SynchronizationContext to force my code back on to the Wizard thread, it fails:

```
    

  

 `_synchronizationContext.Send(Test, null);



    private void Test(object placeholder)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name); 
    }`
```

Thread.CurrentThread.Name usually returns null and in other cases returns "NewStaThread".  I don't want to imply that this behavior is intermittent.  It is just that I have tried many different variations and have called this method from many different locations under different circumstances.

It was my impression that synchronizationContext was supposed to hold a reference to the Wizard thread and when I call the Send method the callback method should execute on the Wizard thread.

Can anyone see which of my assumptions is invalid, or alternatively suggest an avenue for a solution.

Conceptually, I believe that either I have to force my application to return from the DoWork handler back to the Wizard thread or, alternatively, to force it back on to the Wizard thread before launching my DatabaseConnectivityLoss dialog.  It is my understanding that I don't have access to the anonymous thread until it is too late to set it to STA which must be done prior to it starting.

Comment: Could you please summarize your question? It is too long for me to be read